# Setting Super_L as movement key in Linux Mint, to free up alt

Tags: linux-mint

I typically use the left `Alt` key for apps like Photoshop, Maya and Blender (in Photoshop afaik, this key cannot be changed).

Linux Mint 14 with Cinnamon defaults to using the left `Alt` as the movement key (`Alt + leftClick-drag` to move windows, which is great, and I'd like to retain this functionality by swapping it over to the `Super_L` (/`Win` key).

I used dconf-editor to check `mouse-button-modifier` under `org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences` but this is set to `<Super>` already (I have tried setting it to `<Super_L>` to no effect.

Under `Cinnamon Settings - Keyboard - Keyboard Shortcuts - Cinnamon` "Menu Button" is set to `<Super_L>` such that when I press the left super key, it opens the Cinnamon menu.

I got it working nicely in Ubuntu 11.10 a few years back but can't seem to manage it now. In summary, I'd like:

- Alt (left) - unassigned, so that applications (Photoshop, Maya, Blender) can use it in combination with mouse clicks/movements
- Super (left) - to open (and close if possible) the Cinnamon menu, as it does now, but also  to act as the mouse-modifier when I click and drag on Windows

I can't see where `Alt` is assigned at all, so don't know where to turn it off - in Ubuntu, changing the mouse modifier using gconf-editor to the Super key was enough to achieve the above points.

Are Cinnamon restarts/logging in and out/restarting machine necessary steps?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The lines changed in `/usr/lib/cinnamon-settings/cinnamon-settings.py` by [this](https://github.com/linuxmint/Cinnamon/pull/1293/files) patch let me change the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Click</kbd> window movement to <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Click</kbd>.

In Linux Mint 14, this setting appears under **Menu** >> **Preferences** >> **Cinnamon Settings** >> **Windows** and is called **"Modifier to use for modified window click actions"**.

In Linux Mint 18.3, this setting appears under **Menu** >> **Preferences** >> **System Settings** >> **Windows** >> **Behavior** and is called **"Special key to move and resize windows"**.

Comment: This is how I was able to use ALT as my crouch button in Left 4 Dead on Steam. However, setting the key to None didn't work, it had to be Super.

Comment: An anonymous user had suggested this edit, which may be useful to people:  In Linux Mint 17, the setting appears under Menu >> Preferences >> System Settings >> Windows and is called "Special key to move windows".